# Не открывать окно приложения при запуске windows приложения из программы

Tags: c#, windows

Необходимо при запуске windows приложения из программы чтоб не открывалось его окно(работало в фоне)

При запуске использую следующий код

```
string path = @"c:\spice\examples\Monte_Carlo";
var cmd = new Process();//создаем новый объект класса
cmd.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(
        @"c:\spice\bin\ngspice.exe",
        @"c:\spice\examples\Monte_Carlo\MC_2_control.sp");//задаем имя исполняемого файла
cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;//не создавать окно
cmd.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;//спрятать окно
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;// перенаправить вход
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;//перенаправить выход
cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;//обязательный параметр, для работы предыдущих
cmd.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = path;//устанавливаю рабочую директорию

cmd.Start();//запускаем командную строку
cmd.WaitForExit();
```

Проблема в том что не смотря на то что я написал прятать и не создавать окно, окно все равно вылазит.

Как эту проблему решить на c#?

Исходников запускаемой программы нет.
Мы запускаем не консольное приложение.

Comment: Не уверен, но что, если `cmd.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;` написать после старта? Возможно, окно нужной вам программы становится видимым из-за особенности кода этой программы. То есть вы говорите, что окно невидимо, а программа при запуске говорит: "Оппа, окно невидимо. Сделать его видимым" :)

Comment: Или через посылку окну сообщений для его скрытия через `SendMessage()`. Или еще проще, через `ShowWindow()` https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms633548(v=vs.85).aspx . Это API функции, если что :)

Answer (score 2):

Установите свойство [Process.StartInfo.WindowStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.windowstyle(v=vs.110).aspx) в `ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden`

Comment: Но я уже установил это свойство
cmd.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;//спрятать окно
И не помогло.

Comment: Прошу прощения, не заметил. Тем не менее такой способ у меня работает

Comment: `UseShellExecute = false` небось не хватает.